# How do I get TinyMCE 4.x to work with dynamically added DIVs?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I need to use **TinyMCE 4.x** to edit contents in **multiple DIVs**. This works well, except when I dynamically add more DIVs by clicking a button (jquery).

The new DIV shows below the others, but it is not editable at once. After saving the file and reloading it, the new DIV is also editable.

**I see that all existing DIVs has a id="mce_nn" where nn is a unique number.** This seams to be added by TinyMCE itself.

When I dynamically add new DIVs they do not have a id added. However after saving the file and then reloading the page it has a id added.

Is there a way I can get TinyMCE to dynamically to allow me to edit new DIVs?  (All new DIVs had a common class. )

*This is my current TinyMCE init:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "div.mydivsclass",
    inline: true,
 theme: "modern",
    width: "100%",
    height: 300,
```

I appreciate all help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by making a function that activated the new DIV's editor:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function ActivateTinyMCE() {
        tinymce.init({
selector: "div.myclass",
inline: true, etc
```

And then add, as one of the last steps, the ActivateTineMCE() in my "insert-a-new-div"-function:

```
ActivateTinyMCE()
```

Then my insert-function run a TinyMCE init for the new DIV, and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by calling ActivateTinyMCE() function onclick of DIV, but then inline tinymce toolbar was not working for me. Tinymce editor instance was getting initialized but toolbar was not getting visible. I have resolved this issue by firing focus event when tinymce gets initialized as shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ActivateTinyMCE() {
    tinymce.init({
         selector: "div.myclass",
         inline: true,
         ...,
         setup : function(editor) {
            editor.on('init', function() {
                editor._eventDispatcher.fire("focus");
         });
        }
    });
}
```

```
<div class="myclass" onclick="ActivateTinyMCE()"/>
```